# While part of do-while statement skips

Tags: ios, objective-c, do-while

I'm working on a voice memo app, and I'm saving files to a table view. I would like to have the default file name read "New File 1," and if "New File 1" is taken, then it would read "New File 2" and so on.

I'm trying to use a do-while loop to accomplish this, but it is skipping the while statement when I step through the code. Here is what I have:

```
int x = 1;
NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New File %d", x];

NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *testPath =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", documentsPath, firstName];


do
{x++;
    firstName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New File %d", x];
    searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
    testPath =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", documentsPath, firstName];
}
while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:testPath]);
```

If I replace the while portion with something like (x<10), then xcode reads the while statement and naturally the file name turns out to be New File 10. But otherwise, it skips over the while statement.

Any ideas about why this might be?

Thanks

EDIT:

It wasn't skipping. I misunderstood the stepping into the formula. I had added a @".mp4" at the end of my filename later, and I didn't add that to testPath. Now that I added the .mp4, it works great. Thanks for the simplifications and considerations nonetheless.

Comment: Are you certain it is skipping it? Can you provide the evidence?

Comment: Also, there is no need to initialize all of those variables above the `do{}`, you can simply declare them, since your `do{}` will initialize them for you: `NSString *firstName, *documentsPath, *testPath;`, etc.

Comment: Actually, it is more efficient to initiate `searchPaths` and `documentsPath` once, outside the loop, as they don't change.  `firstName` and `testPath` need to remain in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify that, but this worked for me:

```
int x = 0;
NSArray  *searchPaths   = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *testPath;

do
{
    x++;
    testPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New File %d", x]];
}
while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:testPath]);
```

Comment: It worked for me too.  The OP has a problem where x was initialised to 1 and then immediately incremented at the start of the loop, so you end up with "New File 2", not "New File 1"